# How do I force installation of R package from custom repo?

Tags: r, rcpp, install.packages, rcpparmadillo

There's a dependency of dependency which fails to compile when pulled from CRAN at the moment, so the maintainer provided an alternative [Cannot compile RcppArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652764/cannot-compile-rcpparmadillo).

I've tried to install `RcppArmadillo` from that path like so:

```
if(!require("RcppArmadillo")) install.packages("RcppArmadillo", repos="https://rcppcore.github.io/drat", lib = LIB_PATH)
library(RcppArmadillo)

if(!require("sqjin/scAI")) devtools::install_github("sqjin/scAI", lib = LIB_PATH)
library(scAI, lib.loc = LIB_PATH)
```

However, I can see in the logs that `RcppArmadillo` is still being pulled from `CRAN`.

How do I force the installation from custom repo?

Answer (score 2):

By setting your `options("repos")` (named vector) argument in one of your (user or system) startup files you make the alternate location *known* to R. After that R will pick the *highest* (== "newest") version (number).

Here is a block from `help(Startup)` showing one way to do it:

```
 ## Example of Rprofile.site
 local({
   # add MASS to the default packages, set a CRAN mirror
   old <- getOption("defaultPackages"); r <- getOption("repos")
   r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
   options(defaultPackages = c(old, "MASS"), repos = r)
   ## (for Unix terminal users) set the width from COLUMNS if set
   cols <- Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")
   if(nzchar(cols)) options(width = as.integer(cols))
   # interactive sessions get a fortune cookie (needs fortunes package)
   if (interactive())
     fortunes::fortune()
 })
```

where you could just use

```
   r["CRAN"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
   r["Rcpp"] <- "https://RcppCore.github.io/drat"
```

As the RcppCore repo is a `drat` repo you could also consult the `drat` documentation which has other examples and helpers.